# Sending job to remote carte server ends with empty HTTP dialog

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have uploaded my repository to a remote server and when trying to run the job from my local PC on the server, I just get a dialog that says 'http'. Details show

```
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
java.net.UnknownHostException: http
http

    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.sendToSlaveServer(Job.java:1717)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonJobDelegate.executeJob(SpoonJobDelegate.java:1421)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.executeJob(Spoon.java:8603)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.executeFile(Spoon.java:8562)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.runFile(Spoon.java:8527)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.job.JobGraph.runJob(JobGraph.java:3429)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.job.JobGraph$11.widgetSelected(JobGraph.java:1436)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1405)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7989)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9371)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:711)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: http
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.pentaho.di.cluster.SlaveServer.executeAuth(SlaveServer.java:707)
    at org.pentaho.di.cluster.SlaveServer.sendXML(SlaveServer.java:617)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.sendToSlaveServer(Job.java:1694)
    ... 21 more
```

[image: error dialog]

I can reach the server via the browser and Web GUI so in general its available. I am also getting the same error when trying to monitor the carte server from Spoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized what the issue was: don't use http://mylittleserver.com as host but just mylittleserver.com - that fixes it!